# How to prevent a single date overlap in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `EmployeeLeaves` having columns:

```
EmployeeID int,
LeaveTypeID int,
LeaveDate datetime2,
IsHalfDay bit,
DateCreated datetime2,
Createdby varchar
```

I request you to help me out with a trigger that prevent same date for the column "LeaveDate". There are no date ranges like "Todate" and "FromDate" in the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where those conflicting records should go? Hav you looked into Instead of Insert Trigger

Comment: I think a unique constraint makes the most sense long term, but you first have to sort out whether you have any duplicates, and whether you wish to preserve such duplicate dates moving forward.

Comment: It seems like the constraint should include more than just the `LeaveDate` column. Should more than one employee be allowed to leave work each day?

Comment: I have been using After Instead of Trigger here. The conflicting records should not be used here. Only a single occurence of each date need to be there.

Comment: Since the employee is not on leave for a sub-second moment of time, I recommend making `leaveDate` a `date` instead of `datetime`.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer the sample demo,

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeLeaves
  (
     EmployeeID  INT,
     LeaveTypeID INT,
     LeaveDate   DATETIME2,
     IsHalfDay   BIT,
     DateCreated DATETIME2,
     Createdby   VARCHAR(50)
  ) 

insert into EmployeeLeaves
values (1,1,'2016-01-01',0,getdate(),'Admin'),
(2,1,'2016-01-01',0,getdate(),'Admin'),
(3,1,'2016-01-01',0,getdate(),'Admin'),
(4,1,'2016-01-01',0,getdate(),'Admin'),
(5,1,'2016-01-01',0,getdate(),'Admin')

SELECT *
FROM   EmployeeLeaves
```

METHOD-1 using Unique Constraint

```
--Introduce the unique constraint
    ALTER TABLE EmployeeLeaves
      ADD CONSTRAINT uq_employeeid_leavedate UNIQUE (EmployeeId, LeaveDate) 
    --Try to create overlap
    insert into EmployeeLeaves
    values (1,1,'2016-01-01',0,getdate(),'Admin')
    --You will get the following error
    --Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
    --Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'uq_employeeid_leavedate'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EmployeeLeaves'. The duplicate key value is (1, 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0000000).
    --The statement has been terminated.
    --Insert proper date
    insert into EmployeeLeaves
    values (1,1,'2016-01-02',0,getdate(),'Admin')
    --Check the result
    SELECT *
    FROM   EmployeeLeaves
```

METHOD-2 using Instead of trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER Trigger_Test
ON EmployeeLeaves
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1
                FROM   inserted I
                       INNER JOIN EmployeeLeaves e
                               ON i.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
                                  AND i.LeaveDate = e.LeaveDate)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'Overlapping range.',16,1);

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO EmployeeLeaves
            SELECT *
            FROM   inserted
        END;
  END
```

Comment: Thank You. How can we implement it with the help of an instead of insert trigger ?

Comment: please refer method 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique constraint on leave date field or you can check and raise exception using

> `if exist( select top 1  EmployeeID  from table  where EmployeeID = @emploeeid  and
>   datediff(day,leavedate,@applydate)=0  and leavetypeid= @leavetypeid)
>   begin   raise_error('leave already exist',1,1) end`

Comment: Hi. I am sorry to say that the above code is not working . The duplicate records are still getting inserted even though the message is popping up "Leave Already Exist".

Comment: Yes to avoid insertion you have to use return right after raising error..
SQL SERVER doesnot stop execution even if exception is raised.. you have to return 

modificaiton = 
begin   raise_error('leave already exist',1,1)  return end

Comment: Modified Version
if exist( select top 1 EmployeeID from table  where EmployeeID = @emploeeid  and
  datediff(day,leavedate,@applydate)=0  and leavetypeid= @leavetypeid)
  begin   raise_error('leave already exist',1,1) 
Return
end
INsert Statement HERE